# Samson: At A Crossroads

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Samson stood at a crossroads, wondering, not for the first time, why he crawled through the back of his washing mashine into a parallel universe.

The Dubious Dog floated lazily above his head, teasing him; 'you look a bit lost, don't you?'
'I've been walking for five hours and I keep coming to this same set of crossroads. I'm not lost, I know exactly where I am. The exact. same. bloody. crossroads. I'd appreciate some help here.'
'Well, have you even read the sign?'
'It doesn't help!'
'I'm sure it'll tell you where to go, if only you knew what it was saying...'

The Dubious Dog began to disappear, limb by limb, body, face, until only its wagging tongue remained - and then it, too, became nothing more than an illusion in the passing clouds.

'Great.' Samson sighed and looked at the sign again. On the post, there was this shape:

[image]

The signpost also informs him which road goes NE, SE, SW, and NW. The street signs are a bit less clear in their meaning:

> DOWNTOWN
>   1: Notes, e.g. soup
>   2: Twisted sap snake
>   3: Sounds like a digit feasted!
>   4: Golf begins the eternal earthquake
>   5: Double in a hot winter
>
> SIDEWALK
>   1: Regular impact ground covering
>   2: Harvard psychology test in psychiatry
>   3: Waters back a soup
>   4: Seized inside a large whale
>   5: Round writing implement is exposed

Samson, who decided that the situation was wacky enough already, decided to address the reader in a plea for help: 'Which way should I walk to escape the crossroads?

EDIT: Edit to SIDEWALK 2 for specificity

Comment: Was just about to suggest that edit!

Comment: Bit of a cryptic newbie, so still making some minor hiccups, sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Crossword**

Downtown:

> 1. Miso - Notes (mi so), e.g. soup (miso soup)
>
>  Just noticed 'mi' and 'so' are actually the notes 'e' and 'g'.. beautiful!
>  Some contention (*Credit @IAmInPLS*), but there is a Shearer scale that uses 'so' instead of the more common 'sol' as seen [on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)
>
>  2. Asp - Twisted (anagram of sap) sap (asp) snake (asp)
>  3. Ate - Sounds like (homophone) a digit (eight) feasted (ate)
>  4. Tee - Golf (tee) begins (first letters of) the (t) eternal (e) earthquake (e) - *Credit @Techidiot*
>  5. Twin - Double (twin) in (letters inside hot winter) ho(t win)ter

Sidewalk:

> 1. Mat - Regular (alternate letters - *Credit @Techidiot*) impact (m a t) ground covering (mat)
>  <s>2. Chi - Psychology test (Chi squared) in (letters inside psychiatry) psy(chi)atry</s>
>  2. IAT - Harvard psychology test (IAT) in (letters inside psychiatry) psych(iat)ry
>  3. Stew - Waters (wets) back (reverse wets - stew) a soup (stew)
>  4. Sei - (Sei)zed inside (letters in Seized) a large whale (Sei is a type of whale)
>  5. Open - Round (O) writing implement (pen) is exposed (open)

This fits in as..

> `M A . T .`
> `I . A . T`
> `S . T E W`
> `. S E . I`
> `O P . E N`

Note:

> There are a bunch of alternative positions such as:
> `M . A . T`
> `I A . T .`
> `. S T E W`
> `S . . E I`
> `O P E . N`

Alternatively..

> We could write these movable letters to take up four squares each (note the x4 in the diagram):
>  [image: Complete Crossword with Large Letters]

**I'm guessing that Samson should walk..**

> EAST
>
>  The letters that could be written largely to take up four squares (note the x4 in the crossword diagram) are A T S E, which is an anagram of East! To do this, he should take a route between the NE and SE roads.
>
>  .. *although as an anagram it could also mean TASE yourself and take a SEAT!*
>
>  Alternatively..  As East isn't an available direction from the signposts, perhaps it could mean 'at SE' as in head towards the SE.

Comment: @MikeLimburg Thanks! Been working around that for months!

Comment: Spoiler tags are horrendous aren't they! I still don't know how to work these things properly :P

Comment: Downtown 1 is definitely tricky... But you'll know if you've got the right answer.

Comment: @Arth - Deleted my previous post as I noticed you figured it out yourself. (Use two spaces to add a linebreak) You can use the html <br/> too.

Comment: @MikeLimburg I didn't figure it out, I implemented your solution!

Comment: How is 'so' a note?

Comment: @IAmInPLS 'do re mi fa so la ti do'

Comment: You mean 'sol'?

Comment: @IAmInPLS I guess there must be alternatives.. but why would one note end in an 'l' sound when the rest are vowels?

Comment: @Arth Because that's defined like this in many countries? Anyway, this excludes your answer for Downtown 1.

Comment: I don't see how you got MAT..

Comment: @Sid Alternative letters.

Comment: @IAmInPLS OK, I cede that it is rare, but there is a scale that uses it.. the Shearer scale on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge).. also looks like the crossword can be filled in with gaps between the letters of a word.

Comment: @Sid Thanks, hadn't spotted that.. used the other letters I had instead!

Answer (score 3):

To escape the crossroads

> You should walk **EAST**

**DOWNTOWN**

> 1: Notes, e.g. soup -> MI SO -> MISO(Again Thanks to @Arth)
>  2: Twisted sap snake -> ASP
>  3: Sounds like a digit feasted! -> ATE
>  4: Golf begins **t**he **e**ternal **e**arthquake -> TEE
>  5: Doubles in a ho**t win**ter -> TWIN  (Thanks to @Arth)

**SIDEWALK**

> 1: Regular i**m**p**a**c**t** ground covering -> MAT
>  2: Psychology test in psych**iat**ry    -> IAT((Thanks to @Arth)
>  3: Waters back a soup-> WETS -> STEW
>  4: **Sei**zed inside a large whale -> SEI
>  5: Round writing implement is exposed -> Round(O) & Implement(Pen) -> Open

Adding it on the pattern gives -

> [image]

So,

> We should head towards **EAST** as E is at the intersection of 4X4

Comment: e.g. as an anagram indicator is uncommon. I am not sure, the OP meant that.